# Callback function from child component in react

Tags: reactjs

Here i have the parent child communication which works fine.

```
 var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
        update: function() {
            console.log("updated!");
        },
        render: function() {
          <ChildComponent callBack={this.update} />
        }
    })

    var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    preupdate: function() {
        console.log("pre update done!");
    },
    render: function() {
      <button onClick={this.props.callback}>click to update parent</button>
    }
})
```

How shall i call the preupdate function in child component before calling the parent callback method during button Onclick event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call the preupdate function as the click handler. Then when it is done it can invoke the callback.

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    update: function() {
        console.log("updated!");
    },
    render: function() {
      <ChildComponent callBack={this.update} />
    }
})

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    preupdate: function() {
        console.log("pre update done!");
        this.props.callback()
    },
    render: function() {
        <button onClick={this.preupdate.bind(this)}>click to update parent</button>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For react hooks can refer below solution.

- ParentClass

  ```
  function ProfilePage() {

  const successCallBackData = (data) => {
     console.log(data)// can get callback data here
  }
  return (
      <>
        <AlertModal callBack={successCallBackData} /> 
      </>
  );
  }

  export default ProfilePage;
  ```
- ChildClass

  ```
  const AlertModal = (props) =>{

  const goBack = () => {
      props.callBack('hello');// can pass callback data here
  }
  return (
      <>
        <div>
        <Button className="btn-round" color="danger"   onClick={goBack}>
          Go Back
              </Button>
        </div>
      </>
  );
  }

  export default AlertModal;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<button onClick={(args)=>{this.preupdate(args);this.props.callback(args);}>click to update parent</button>
```

You'll also need to redefine the preupdate function like so:

```
preupdate: ()=> {
        console.log("pre update done!");
    }
```

so that you retain the `this` context while making a call to this method.